# How to efficiently re-arrange row values to be in sorted order in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure what to include about background - using MySQL / MariaDB with InnoDB and mixed with python.

I have some pretty massive tables and among other things, they have 3 numeric columns, let's say A, B & C. Is there an efficient way to update each row to have the numbers in A, B and C to be increasing (or decreasing) order?

E.g. as of now:

```
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | Other data |  A  |  B  |  C  |
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | Something  | 2.0 | 1.3 | 1.0 |
|  2 | Something  | 1.0 | 3.0 | 2.0 |
|  3 | Something  | 1.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 |
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Would like it to be:

```
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | Other data |  A  |  B  |  C  |
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | Something  | 1.0 | 1.3 | 2.0 |
|  2 | Something  | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |
|  3 | Something  | 1.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: Are you sure your schema is correct?  Should these be a single column with multiple rows?

Comment: Agree with MK - when you have data of the same "type" occurring in multiple columns (but where you now want to compare/manipulate them all together), it's usually an indicator that the data model is wrong. Ought to be separate rows and possible the A,B,C labels are in the wrong place too - they may be *data* that has been mismodelled as metadata.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow about why they should be separate rows. I'm trying to keep the exact contents of the DB vague. But for instance, the row with ID = 1 is a specific item with 3 measures associated with it, ID = 2 is a completely different item with it's own 3 measures. A, B, C are placeholder names here. The DB should've been put together such that A<=B<=C from the start, but I forgot a line of code. I'm trying to go back and fix all of the rows now and I'm looking to see if there's an efficient way to do it that I wasn't aware of.

But it looks like I should just create new tables.

Comment: @user982835 - all of the "measures" appear to be interchangeable. What will you do if a fourth measure is required? Under the current system, you have to make schema changes to accommodate it. If you want to query for e.g. any `id` with a measure between 1.5 and 1.7 you have to write a complex query because the data is spread across multiple columns. When all of the data is in a single column, you'll be able to write queries that leverage SQLs advantages - working set-based with grouping and aggregates.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get into the details, but there will only ever be 3 measures and they should be in sorted order. But in any case, I'm curious now, if this was not the case, are you saying that I should have an entire separate record per measure or that I should/am able to have multiple values/columns per column in a single record?

Answer (score 0):

An efficient solution?  You need to do an `update` on all the rows, and that's not efficient.

If you have only three columns, then you can use simple `case` logic if the values are all different:

```
select id, . . .,
       least(a, b, c) as a,
       (case when a not in (least(a, b, c), greatest(a, b, c)) then a
             when b not in (least(a, b, c), greatest(a, b, c)) then b
             else c
        end) as b, 
       greatest(a, b, c) as b
from t;
```

The logic gets a bit more complicated if you have duplicates or `NULL` values, but something similar can be adapted.  It becomes more cumbersome if you have more than 3 columns.

This is easily adapted to an update.  If you really want to store these in a table, I would putting them in another table using `create table as`.  `Insert`s are faster than massive numbers of `update`s.

Comment: Doesn't that need `else c`? And then the final alias is probably worth correcting too.